# Efficienty `cd' into programming workspace

Tags: linux, text, editing

My *directory structure* for all things programming is currently like this -

The folders are under this directory:

```
/home/borax12/programming

-android
-java
-GoogleApps
```

It is a *pain to every time `cd` to this directory* for any programming. So I wanted to know whats the *best practice* to access your programming documents efficiently.

I was of the opinion to *create symlinks* to all those folders, but I don't want my home folder to look cluttered.

Even if I make symlinks, can I hide them somehow?

Comment: Have a look att this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/353161/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-shell-zsh-preferably-about-a-command/353168#353168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use aliases (put them in your `~/.bashrc`):

```
alias ,p='cd /home/borax12/programming'
alias ,pj='cd /home/borax12/programming/java'
alias ,pa='cd /home/borax12/programming/android'
```

So these aliases start with commas, and keep you 3-4 characters away from code.

```
,p<CR>
```

And then there is [`autojump`](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki) for overall `cd` goodness (written by, IIRC, a StackOverflow user).